# Chi-square test for bank customer churn

Tags: r, dplyr

I have sample of customers of a bank that reflects the characteristics of the clients and whether the bank continues to work with them or not (churn). The sample concerns 10,000 customers, while the files "Train.Data" and "Test.Data" include the information we need.

Data :

Train Data:

```
> dput(head(datab1))
structure(list(RowNumber = 1:6, CustomerId = c(15634602L, 15647311L, 
15619304L, 15701354L, 15737888L, 15574012L), Surname = c("Hargrave", 
"Hill", "Onio", "Boni", "Mitchell", "Chu"), CreditScore = c(619L, 
608L, 502L, 699L, 850L, 645L), Geography = c("France", "Spain", 
"France", "France", "Spain", "Spain"), Gender = c("Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male"), Age = c(42L, 41L, 42L, 
39L, 43L, 44L), Tenure = c(2L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 8L), Balance = c(0, 
83807.86, 159660.8, 0, 125510.82, 113755.78), NumOfProducts = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), HasCrCard = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), IsActiveMember = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), EstimatedSalary = c(101348.88, 112542.58, 
113931.57, 93826.63, 79084.1, 149756.71), Exited = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Test Data:

```
> dput(head(datab2))
structure(list(RowNumber = 8001:8006, CustomerId = c(15629002L, 
15798053L, 15753895L, 15595426L, 15645815L, 15632848L), Surname = c("Hamilton", 
"Nnachetam", "Blue", "Madukwe", "Mills", "Ferrari"), CreditScore = c(747L, 
707L, 590L, 603L, 615L, 634L), Geography = c("Germany", "Spain", 
"Spain", "Spain", "France", "France"), Gender = c("Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female"), Age = c(36L, 32L, 37L, 57L, 
45L, 36L), Tenure = c(8L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L), Balance = c(102603.3, 
0, 0, 105000.85, 0, 69518.95), NumOfProducts = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), HasCrCard = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), IsActiveMember = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), EstimatedSalary = c(180693.61, 126475.79, 
133535.99, 87412.24, 164886.64, 116238.39), Exited = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Im running Chi-square test and my code comes with the above error and i cant understand what its my fault ?*

```
chi.square <- vector()
p.value <- vector()
cateVar <- datab1 %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Exited) %>% 
  keep(is.factor)

for (i in 1:length(cateVar)) {
  p.value[i] <- chisq.test(datab1$Exited, unname(unlist(cateVar[i])), correct = FALSE)[3]$p.value
  chi.square[i] <- unname(chisq.test(datab1$Exited, unname(unlist(cateVar[i])), correct = FALSE)[1]$statistic)
}

chi_sqaure_test <- tibble(variable = names(cateVar)) %>% 
  add_column(chi.square = chi.square) %>% 
  add_column(p.value = p.value)
knitr::kable(chi_sqaure_test)
```

Error :

```
> chi.square <- vector()
> p.value <- vector()
> cateVar <- datab1 %>% 
+   dplyr::select(-Exited) %>% 
+   keep(is.factor)
> 
> for (i in 1:length(cateVar)) {
+   p.value[i] <- chisq.test(datab1$Exited, unname(unlist(cateVar[i])), correct = FALSE)[3]$p.value
+   chi.square[i] <- unname(chisq.test(datab1$Exited, unname(unlist(cateVar[i])), correct = FALSE)[1]$statistic)
+ }
Error in `[.data.frame`(cateVar, i) : undefined columns selected
> 
> chi_sqaure_test <- tibble(variable = names(cateVar)) %>% 
+   add_column(chi.square = chi.square) %>% 
+   add_column(p.value = p.value)
> knitr::kable(chi_sqaure_test)


|variable |chi.square |p.value |
|:--------|:----------|:-------|
```

Any suggestions in order to solve this situation and continue the process correctly ?!

Comment: Generally, try to make the example you post completely reproducible so that it's easy to simply copy the code and run it to get the observed error. If you don't, there's a risk that readers will give up but there's also a risk that the code they run is different from what you run. In this case, the use of the `keep` function requires a `library(purrr)` call. Once I do that, I can see that the `cateVar` object has no columns because the `datab1` variable has no factors in it.

Comment: I have solved my problem here thank you @AndrewChisholm ! I can now continue my work , i had made a mistake with the factors of my data. Thank again !